# MAAS nodes hung at commisioning

Tags: maas

Got another machine up and running 12.04. All three of these machines have different cpu  a dell amd64,hp intel, and MX-3203 VIA. I have a copy of maas and a desktop in all three.  No matter which way I furnish maas on any machine the nodes hang with commissioning status.  Booting the newest machine dell amd64 to maas is actually the worse. One node hangs at commissiong [MX-3203 VIA] and the other node has problem with cobbler server  [HP intel]. All the while its constantly going into NAK bailout. I've gone through the bugs  and tried everything but no fix has worked. Can't even remove the node to start over.  Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check the clocks on the machines.  If they are too far out of sync it stops OAuth from working which makes the commissioning script hang when it tries to access the metadata on the maas server.